# How do you get a friend's Super Secret Base?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

In Pokémon ORAS, you randomly receive Super Secret Bases through the BuzzNav, which picks from passersby, acquaintances, and friends. I've had to wait for quite a while before randomly getting a base from people in my friends list.

Is there a way to ensure you'll receive a friend's base instead of relying on random chance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a base, you also get a QR code associated with this base. All you have to do is to scan the QR code of your friend's base. Then, if you go to the location of your friend's base, you will be able to find it.

For that, your friend needs to share his/her QR code with you. He needs to go to the PC in his base, and to use the "Manage QR Code patterns" option. If he then select "Share a Secret Base", and then "Your Message", he will get a screen with the associated QR Code.

On your side, you also need to go on your base's PC, and select the "Manage QR Code patterns" option. Then use the "Find a Secret Base" option, and you will be able to scan the code.

You might have to wait after midnight for the base to appear on your game.

Comment: I was under the impression that bases received from QR codes would go to the special room in Mossdeep City, instead of any base in routes. Is that wrong?

Comment: I can certify that you can. I used some QR codes to get the bases of people with teams of 3 Blissey for easy experience, and they were located where it was expected.

Comment: Alright, thanks for confirmation. I genuinely forgot about this feature since I never used it.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer The room in Mossdeep is reserved for developer Junichi Masuda's secret base (obtainable https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/2n8au4/how_to_unlock_the_door_in_mossdeep_city/). And I believe you can have just as many QR bases as ordinary bases, though this is just speculation.

Comment: @chif-ii There is a maximum. You can have a total of 30 bases on your game at the same time (15 as favorites, and 15 others).